# Binding FlirOne AAR with Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to use FlirOne Thermal SDK in Xamarin project. So far I've created binding projects for thermalsdk-release.aar and androidsdk-release.aar libraries using following mappings:

```xml
//EnumMethods.xml
<enum-method-mappings>
  <mapping jni-class="javax/jmdns/impl/DNSCache">
    <method jni-name="entrySet" parameter="return" clr-enum-type="System.Collections.ICollection" />
  </mapping>

  <mapping jni-class="javax/jmdns/impl/DNSCache._CacheEntry">
    <method jni-name="getKey" parameter="return" clr-enum-type="Java.Lang.Object" />
  </mapping>

  <mapping jni-class="javax/jmdns/impl/DNSCache._CacheEntry">
    <method jni-name="getValue" parameter="return" clr-enum-type="Java.Lang.Object" />
  </mapping>

  <mapping jni-class="javax/jmdns/impl/JmDNSImpl.ServiceTypeEntry.SubTypeEntry">
    <method jni-name="getKey" parameter="return" clr-enum-type="Java.Lang.Object" />
  </mapping>

  <mapping jni-class="javax/jmdns/impl/JmDNSImpl.ServiceTypeEntry.SubTypeEntry">
    <method jni-name="getValue" parameter="return" clr-enum-type="Java.Lang.Object" />
  </mapping>

  <mapping jni-class="javax/jmdns/impl/JmDNSImpl.ServiceTypeEntry">
    <method jni-name="entrySet" parameter="return" clr-enum-type="System.Collections.ICollection" />
  </mapping>
</enum-method-mappings>

//Metadata.xml
<metadata>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.github.mjdev.libaums.fs.fat32']/class[@name='FatDirectory']/method[@name='createDirectory' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='java.lang.String']]" name="visibility">public</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.github.mjdev.libaums.fs.fat32']/class[@name='FatDirectory']/method[@name='createDirectory' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='java.lang.String']]" name="final">true</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.github.mjdev.libaums.fs.fat32']/class[@name='FatDirectory']/method[@name='createDirectory' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='java.lang.String']]" name="managedReturn">IUsbFile</attr>

  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.github.mjdev.libaums.fs.fat32']/class[@name='FatDirectory']/method[@name='createFile' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='java.lang.String']]" name="visibility">public</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.github.mjdev.libaums.fs.fat32']/class[@name='FatDirectory']/method[@name='createFile' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='java.lang.String']]" name="final">true</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.github.mjdev.libaums.fs.fat32']/class[@name='FatDirectory']/method[@name='createFile' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='java.lang.String']]" name="managedReturn">IUsbFile</attr>

  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.flir.thermalsdk.live.remote']/class[@name='RemoteMeasurementType']" name="visibility">public</attr>
</metadata>
```

In the demo application, I've added references to binding libraries (AndroidSdkBinding, ThermalSdkBinding) and after building project I get an error in the following java class:

```java
package mono.com.flir.thermalsdk.androidsdk.live.connectivity;


public class UsbPermissionHandler_UsbPermissionListenerImplementor
    extends java.lang.Object
    implements
        mono.android.IGCUserPeer,
        com.flir.thermalsdk.androidsdk.live.connectivity.UsbPermissionHandler.UsbPermissionListener
{
/** @hide */
    public static final String __md_methods;
    static {
        __md_methods = 
            "";
        mono.android.Runtime.register ("Com.Flir.Thermalsdk.Androidsdk.Live.Connectivity.UsbPermissionHandler+IUsbPermissionListenerImplementor, AndroidSdkBinding", UsbPermissionHandler_UsbPermissionListenerImplementor.class, __md_methods);
    }


    public UsbPermissionHandler_UsbPermissionListenerImplementor ()
    {
        super ();
        if (getClass () == UsbPermissionHandler_UsbPermissionListenerImplementor.class)
            mono.android.TypeManager.Activate ("Com.Flir.Thermalsdk.Androidsdk.Live.Connectivity.UsbPermissionHandler+IUsbPermissionListenerImplementor, AndroidSdkBinding", "", this, new java.lang.Object[] {  });
    }

    private java.util.ArrayList refList;
    public void monodroidAddReference (java.lang.Object obj)
    {
        if (refList == null)
            refList = new java.util.ArrayList ();
        refList.add (obj);
    }

    public void monodroidClearReferences ()
    {
        if (refList != null)
            refList.clear ();
    }
}
```

I get the following error after building:

UsbPermissionHandler_UsbPermissionListenerImplementor is not abstract and does not override abstract method error(ErrorType,Identity) in UsbPermissionListener.

I can temporarily modify this class and add the "abstract" modifier and I can see that the following works.

```cs
using Com.Flir.Thermalsdk;
using Com.Flir.Thermalsdk.Androidsdk;

ThermalSdkAndroid.Init(ApplicationContext);
showSDKversion(ThermalSdkAndroid.Version);
showSDKCommitHash(ThermalSdkAndroid.CommitHash);
```

Is there anything I can do here so that java class is correctly generated?

Answer (score 1):

This solution works, but on some versions of VS or something else, it fails to generate proper binding code.

Binding assembly should contain a single AAR file and build action should be set to LibraryProjectZip.

So there should be two binding assemblies like:

- Binding.AndroidThermalSdk (thermalsdk-release.aar)
- Binding.AndroidSdk (android-release.aar) that references binding above

Then transformations should be configured as:

```xml
<!-- Binding.AndroidSdk  -->
<enum-method-mappings>
  <mapping jni-class="javax/jmdns/impl/DNSCache">
    <method jni-name="entrySet" parameter="return" clr-enum-type="System.Collections.ICollection" />
  </mapping>

  <mapping jni-class="javax/jmdns/impl/DNSCache._CacheEntry">
    <method jni-name="getKey" parameter="return" clr-enum-type="Java.Lang.Object" />
  </mapping>

  <mapping jni-class="javax/jmdns/impl/DNSCache._CacheEntry">
    <method jni-name="getValue" parameter="return" clr-enum-type="Java.Lang.Object" />
  </mapping>

  <mapping jni-class="javax/jmdns/impl/JmDNSImpl.ServiceTypeEntry.SubTypeEntry">
    <method jni-name="getKey" parameter="return" clr-enum-type="Java.Lang.Object" />
  </mapping>

  <mapping jni-class="javax/jmdns/impl/JmDNSImpl.ServiceTypeEntry.SubTypeEntry">
    <method jni-name="getValue" parameter="return" clr-enum-type="Java.Lang.Object" />
  </mapping>

  <mapping jni-class="javax/jmdns/impl/JmDNSImpl.ServiceTypeEntry">
    <method jni-name="entrySet" parameter="return" clr-enum-type="System.Collections.ICollection" />
  </mapping>
</enum-method-mappings>

<metadata>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.github.mjdev.libaums.fs.fat32']/class[@name='FatDirectory']/method[@name='createDirectory' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='java.lang.String']]" name="visibility">public</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.github.mjdev.libaums.fs.fat32']/class[@name='FatDirectory']/method[@name='createDirectory' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='java.lang.String']]" name="final">true</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.github.mjdev.libaums.fs.fat32']/class[@name='FatDirectory']/method[@name='createDirectory' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='java.lang.String']]" name="managedReturn">IUsbFile</attr>

  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.github.mjdev.libaums.fs.fat32']/class[@name='FatDirectory']/method[@name='createFile' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='java.lang.String']]" name="visibility">public</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.github.mjdev.libaums.fs.fat32']/class[@name='FatDirectory']/method[@name='createFile' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='java.lang.String']]" name="final">true</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.github.mjdev.libaums.fs.fat32']/class[@name='FatDirectory']/method[@name='createFile' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='java.lang.String']]" name="managedReturn">IUsbFile</attr>

  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.flir.thermalsdk.live.remote']/class[@name='RemoteMeasurementType']" name="visibility">public</attr>

  <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.flir.thermalsdk.androidsdk.live.connectivity']/class[@name='UsbPermissionHandler']"/>
  <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.flir.thermalsdk.androidsdk.meterlink']/class[@name='BluetoothAdapterAndroid']"/>
</metadata>

<!-- Binding.AndroidThermalSdk -->
<enum-method-mappings>
  <mapping jni-class="javax/jmdns/impl/DNSCache">
    <method jni-name="entrySet" parameter="return" clr-enum-type="System.Collections.ICollection" />
  </mapping>

  <mapping jni-class="javax/jmdns/impl/DNSCache._CacheEntry">
    <method jni-name="getKey" parameter="return" clr-enum-type="Java.Lang.Object" />
  </mapping>

  <mapping jni-class="javax/jmdns/impl/DNSCache._CacheEntry">
    <method jni-name="getValue" parameter="return" clr-enum-type="Java.Lang.Object" />
  </mapping>

  <mapping jni-class="javax/jmdns/impl/JmDNSImpl.ServiceTypeEntry.SubTypeEntry">
    <method jni-name="getKey" parameter="return" clr-enum-type="Java.Lang.Object" />
  </mapping>

  <mapping jni-class="javax/jmdns/impl/JmDNSImpl.ServiceTypeEntry.SubTypeEntry">
    <method jni-name="getValue" parameter="return" clr-enum-type="Java.Lang.Object" />
  </mapping>

  <mapping jni-class="javax/jmdns/impl/JmDNSImpl.ServiceTypeEntry">
    <method jni-name="entrySet" parameter="return" clr-enum-type="System.Collections.ICollection" />
  </mapping>
</enum-method-mappings>

<metadata>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.github.mjdev.libaums.fs.fat32']/class[@name='FatDirectory']/method[@name='createDirectory' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='java.lang.String']]" name="visibility">public</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.github.mjdev.libaums.fs.fat32']/class[@name='FatDirectory']/method[@name='createDirectory' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='java.lang.String']]" name="final">true</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.github.mjdev.libaums.fs.fat32']/class[@name='FatDirectory']/method[@name='createDirectory' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='java.lang.String']]" name="managedReturn">IUsbFile</attr>

  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.github.mjdev.libaums.fs.fat32']/class[@name='FatDirectory']/method[@name='createFile' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='java.lang.String']]" name="visibility">public</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.github.mjdev.libaums.fs.fat32']/class[@name='FatDirectory']/method[@name='createFile' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='java.lang.String']]" name="final">true</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.github.mjdev.libaums.fs.fat32']/class[@name='FatDirectory']/method[@name='createFile' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='java.lang.String']]" name="managedReturn">IUsbFile</attr>

  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.flir.thermalsdk.live.remote']/class[@name='RemoteMeasurementType']" name="visibility">public</attr>

</metadata>
```

If you get syntax errors during build then I am not sure what is the reason.